# Protection.removeEditor(email address) is taking time

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to protect (lock) some cells within a sheet for a user (XXXXX@gmail.com), to whom I am sharing my Google Sheet.

Here is my code :

```
var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
for (var i=2;i<=lastrow;i++)
 {
var cellFileRcvdDt = source.getRange(i, 5);

   cellFileRcvdDt.setNote('Protected by ' +me+'  on '+  new Date());
   var protection = cellFileRcvdDt.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');
   var usr = 'XXXXX@gmail.com'
    protection.removeEditor(user); //taking too much time to complete this statement.
}
```

The code is working fine i.e. protecting the cells for user 'XXXXX@gmail.com'.

The problem is, while running the script the line `protection.removeEditor(user);` is taking significant amount of time i.e. 2-3 mins, which is causing the script to time out.

Can someone please explain why is this happening? Am I missing something important here? what is the alternative way of removing this user so that they're not able to edit the cells?

See the entire code :

```
// 5 rows x 16 columns grid.
function LockDateCells(){
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  var LOCK_USER = 'LOCKUSER@gmail.com';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tracker");
  var lastrow = source.getLastRow();
   for (var i=2;i<=lastrow;i++){
    console.info('File Received Date locking start...', 'LockDateCells', 1);   
    var cellFileRcvdDt = source.getRange(i, 5);  
    cellFileRcvdDt.setNote('Protected by ' +me+'  on '+  new Date());
    var protection = cellFileRcvdDt.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');
    protection.removeEditor(LOCK_USER);  
  }
}
```

[image: My Spreadsheet]

Comment: Well, each method call takes some time (small amount), and you are making calls `lastrow-2` number of times, which quickly escalates execution time. Could you please clarify why do you need to protect individual ranges instead of a large one, I can't find any conditional statements?

Comment: I tried calling the method outside the loop , i.e. single call of  protection.removeEditor (usr) is still taking more than 60 secs. Well, requirement is to share the sheet to a single user who should not edit a particular cells of my sheet. Curious, what is actually processed inside the method that takes too much amount of time?

Comment: Problem is not really lies on the loop, problem is on the line ``` protection.removeEditor(usr)```. Pls help.

Comment: How many rows are there in your spreadsheet? It takes appx. 0.3 sec to remove the editor from a 150 x 5 range grid, so I am not sure what can make the `removeEditor()` method run so slow in your case. Btw, is this >60 sec info from the execution transcript?

Comment: It's a 6 rows and 16 columns based spreadsheet.  Yes, this is >60 sec that  `protection.removeEditor(usr)` is taking time to complete .  Can you try running my code to check from your end whether it's taking time or not?  Am I missing any significant point that is required? Pls help. I am stuck on this for long time, could not understand what is the alternative.

Comment: Is the goal to make it so that only you can edit the protected range? if so, I would suggest following the first example at [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection), it shows how to remove all other editors and make it so only you can edit the protected range.

Comment: Goal is to get rid of slowness problem while executing the google script statement ```protection.removeEditor(usr)``` . please see the original post with code snippet.

Comment: Hm, I've analyzed the code, ran a few tests and there is no way a simple 1×1 range (and this is what you get via `getRange(i,5)` should cause such a delay. Could you please post the whole function just to make sure? If nothing obvious therr, I would suggest [submitting an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com) - it starts to look like one

Comment: Pls find the entire code in the original post

Comment: Hi SKC! Thank you for responding and posting the whole code - my runs even on a bigger scale end in a reasonable timeframe... Definitely worth submitting an issue to tracker in my opinion - unless we all miss something. Could you provide a screenshot of sample spreadsheet data you are running the script on?

Comment: Spreadsheet image is attached via this link (https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpEe5.jpg) in the original post..please look..let me know what is missing there.

Comment: What I meant by asking about the goal was whether you intended for you to be the only one with edit permission. The files could be shared with many users, which could be leading to the delay.

Comment: Hi Amolina...file is shared with only one user

Comment: In that case you should definitely submit an issue, as suggested by Oleg, this behavior is unusual.

Comment: I have created another spreadsheet and run the script, i see  the statement ```protection.removeEditor()``` is quite fast now. It implies that my spreadsheet is having some issues which cause the removeEditor() taking longer time to complete. I am not sure what was the problem in the spreadsheet, but there are problems (may be having cell color, bold font, non-ASCII characters, other properties etc). Oleg can help here.

Thanks everyone for your support, I am closing this topic as answered.

Comment: Hi SKC! Please, in the future, put "@Username" [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) for us to recieve notifications of reply - it's hard to keep track if a question is still active otherwise. I recreated it using your data - nothing seems to suggest that anything in the spreadsheet itself could cause the issue. If there are no privacy concerns, could you enable  link sharing, maybe we can check? And agreed with @AMolina, definitely worth the issue tracker

Comment: I notice that you loop through `var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();`, could you try to set a particular range (`A1:D4` for example) and do the protection over the entire range? Also check there are no values at the bottom of your sheet, by the screenshot you shared there didn't seem to be too many rows, there could be a value in the bottom making the code loop too many times.